# Binary tree (S-Expression) pretty printer

Tags: c, tree, formatting

I'm just trying to create a binary tree, and a pretty printer for it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned long Leaf;

struct NodeStruct {
    struct TreeStruct * left;
    struct TreeStruct * right;
};
typedef struct NodeStruct Node;

struct TreeStruct {
    char isNode;
    union {
        Node node;
        Leaf leaf;
    } value;
};
typedef struct TreeStruct Tree;

Tree node(Tree* left, Tree* right){
    Tree result;
    result.isNode = 1;
    result.value.node.left = left;
    result.value.node.right = right;
    return result;
};

Tree leaf(unsigned long x){
    Tree result;
    result.isNode = 0;
    result.value.leaf = x;
    return result;
};

void print(Tree* tree, int isRoot){
  if (!tree->isNode){
        printf("%lu",tree->value.leaf);
        return;
    };
    printf("(");
    print(tree->value.node.left,0);
    printf(" ");
    print(tree->value.node.right,0);
    printf(")");
};

int main(){
    Tree a = leaf(1);
    Tree b = leaf(2);
    Tree c = leaf(3);
    Tree d = leaf(4);
    Tree ab = node(&a,&b);
    Tree cd = node(&c,&d);
    Tree abcd = node(&ab,&cd);
    print(&abcd,1);
};
```

There are so many things that sound wrong to me, yet I don't know how I'm supposed to improve this in C. Ideas?

Also, what if I wanted to return the string instead of printing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Disclaimer: I am a C++ coder, but I researched to make sure none of that made it into this advise.

It looks alright, there are a couple little things.

- First, explicitly state that `main()` takes no arguments.  This is applicable to all functions in C:

  ```
  int main(void)
  ```
- `leaf` should take an argument of `Leaf` rather than `unsigned long`, this means that you will only have one line to change if you ever want your tree to hold something else.

  ```
  Tree leaf(Leaf x)
  ```
- Either use `<stdbool.h>` if on a C99 compiler, or explicitly define `true` and `false` rather than just using `1` and `0`. This will make your code more self documenting.

  ```
  #include <stdbool.h>

  #define true 1
  #define false 0
  ```
- Again, if using `<stdbool.h>`, use the `bool` type or roll your own:

  ```
  typedef int bool
  ```
- If you are using C11 then you can use anonymous unions to simplify your `TreeStruct`.  It will also mean you can remove the now superfluous `.value` throughout your code.

  ```
  struct TreeStruct
  {
      bool isNode;
      union
      {
          Node node;
          Leaf leaf;
      };
  };
  ```
- You don't actually use the `isRoot` value passed to print, but it can be used to print a newline at the end.

  ```
  void print(Tree * tree, bool isRoot)
  {
      if (!tree->isNode)
      {
          printf("%lu", tree->leaf);
          return;
      };

      printf("(");
      print(tree->node.left, false);
      printf(" ");
      print(tree->node.right, false);
      printf(")");

      if (isRoot)
      {
          printf("\n");
      }
  };
  ```
- As a matter of personal preference, I like to space things out a bit more, as you can see above.